# How can a 3 Mbit/s connection be faster in actual use than a 10 Mbit/s connection?

Tags: internet, internet-speed

Can anyone enlighten me about this. I live in a place where internet connection isn't really that good. We switch to different plans just to get the best connection we can get. We currently have the 10mbps plan (LTE signal, not wired). Whenever I test on Speedtest.net, it does reach up to 5 UL/10 DL, ping: 20-50. I went to a friend's place who has a DSL (wired) connection of 3mpbs. The speedtest shows up to 2 UL/3 DL - ping: 10-50, but it is noticeably faster when browsing and downloading files.

I tried downloading a 250mb file and the download speed was way consistent that ours at home.

We have a 10mpbs connection, theirs is 3mpbs. How come their internet connection is faster?

Comment: ICMP roundtrip times of <50 ms in both cases indicates you are testing against a server geographically and/or network-wise fairly close to you, but you say nothing that give any clue as to how far you are (network-wise) from the sites that you feel are slow. Might it be that your friend's ISP has better upstream peering? Try having your friend ping a site that you feel are slow *at the same time that you do the same*, and compare the results. Roundtrip times can vary especially if the network is somehow marginal, and certainly can have an impact on both throughput and more importantly lag.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of factors at play, but in most cases you won't be able to get the full bandwidth of a higher speed connection for a single site.  If the download site can't provide a feed faster than 3Mbits/sec, your speed won't be usable for the download.

- After a certain amount of data has been sent, the sender will wait for an `ACK`nkowlegement that the data has been received before sent before sending more data.  There is a windowing process used to increase bandwidth, but even that has limits.  Windowing is highly sensitive to dropped packets, and may not respond well to out of order packets.
- The sending site needs to have the available capacity to send data at your speed.  Transmission is done on a fair share basis, so they would need far more than 10 Mbits/sec to keep up to your connection, but could handle three 3 Mbits/sec connections with a 10Mbit/sec connection.
- There may be proxies between you and the content, and they may alter the speed at which you can access content.  (There was a time when I got faster downloads of popular content from an inter-continental feed.)
- Anywhere along the path there can be switch which is running at or near capacity.  That will slow taffic down in a number of ways.

When broadband Internet was first starting many large sites could only serve pages at about 56Kbps (high-speed dial-up speed).  However, you could browse multiple sites at that speed.  That didn't last long as they added capacity and can now serve content much faster.

Comment: There is also the possibility (related to your second point) that the site cannot serve the data fast enough to saturate a 10 Mb/s connection, even if they too have one. For example, they might be serving static images off rotational HDDs, thus severely constraining the achievable IOPS. If many visitors request different such images which are not in the server's cache, throughput will be limited by the IOPS achievable by the storage layer. HDDs can do about 50-250 IOPS, SSDs often >10K IOPS. (This is simplified to fit inside the comment space, but accurate for a first order approximation.)